# Automatically cache files read in with pandas in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have some functions that involve reading in data from the disk (`data = pandas.read_table('my_data.txt')`). When I call the cells that read in those files, it can be slow. Sometimes the underlying files have not changed, so it is a waste of time to read the file again.

It would be great to have a way to automatically cache all files read in, such that they are stored in memory for quicker retrieval. If the file has changed (e.g. by checking that the modification time is newer than the cache time), it would be read in again. Otherwise, it would just grab the contents from memory.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can't memory is volatile, that's why the computer gods invented disk

Comment: @itprorh66 indeed any file would need to be read in at least one time whenever the kernel is (re)started, but if a cell is re-executed and the underlying file hasn't changed then it is entirely possible retrieve a cached version in memory

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
from functools import lru_cache
import pandas as pd

def _get_time_last_modified(filepath):
    # filepath is string
    # returns pandas.Timestamp

@lru_cache
def _get_file(filepath, timestamp):
    return pd.read_table(filepath)

def get_file(filepath):
    time_last_modified = _get_time_last_modified(filepath).value  # convert to int as lru_cache needs hashable params
    return _get_file(filepath, time_last_modified)
```

Have a look at the `lru_cache` docs, and decide what size you want the cache to be. You will need to implement the code for determining when the file was last modified